# Php get the actual results when doing calculations

Tags: php

In php I am doing multiplication. Here my code is like this

```
$a = 25.20
$multiplication = (int)$a * 2;
echo $multiplication;
```

here its showing 50

So how can I get the actual values here?

Comment: *So how can I get the actual values here?* What do you mean with this? `50.40` ? If yes, maybe don't cast it to int ?!?

Comment: @Rizier123  yes. I want to get the actual decimal value

Comment: Well, do as @Rizier123 said: don't cast it to `int` but rather to `float`.

Comment: "I ripped apart this piece of paper. Why is it shredded? I need an intact piece of paper". If you want a floating point result, then DON'T cast to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `int` datatype as a result.

Use:

```
$a = 25.20;
$multiplication = (float)$a * 2;
echo $multiplication;
```

In php you don't need to do type casting because php do it for you.But if you want to you can. In your code you are using `int` as datatype but you want decimal values as datatype for that you have to use `float`.

Simplest way to do it:

```
$a = 25.20;
$multiplication = $a * 2;
echo $multiplication;
```

You will get same result.

Answer (score 0):

you should `cast float` instead of int, for you to return decimal places

```
$a = 25.20;
$multiplication = (float)$a * 2;
echo $multiplication;
```